# How to clone a repository with unmerged pull request

Tags: git, zurb-foundation, kaminari

I want to clone a repository with unmerged pull request.

Specifically, [kaminari_themas](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_themes) with this [pull request for zurb-foundation](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_themes/pull/14) is what I need.
How can I clone it?

Comment: Why don't just clone the repository where the merge request is from ? https://github.com/linojon/kaminari_themes

Comment: @Jahnux73 personally, I often fork repositories just to perform bugfixes and then create pull requests, so it might be a good idea to stick with the main upstream and merge in changes as necessary. Otherwise you might end up falling behind upstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the main repository normally, and then add the repository from which the pull request originates (in this case `linojon/kaminari_themes`) as an additional remote, e.g.:

```
git clone git://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_themes
cd kaminari_themes
git remote add linojon git://github.com/linojon/kaminari_themes
git fetch linojon
```

And then cherry-pick the relevant commit referenced in the pull request:

```
git cherry-pick cc5a5bcee7fa17ac984eb4f3900bc7594f0b4bcc
```